# How to propagate a release-specific bug fix to other builds?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I was wondering what's the best way to propagate a release-specific bug fix to other builds in TFS?

Suppose the minor bug fix made in 1.2.1 also needed to exist in 1.3.0, but could no longer "go through" Main b/c it has been updated with 2.0.0 changes:

> **Dev**
>
> - 2.0.0
>
> Main
>
> **Release**
>
> - 1.2.0
> - 1.3.0
> - 2.0.0
>
>   **Build**
>
>   - 1.2.1

One option I suppose would be to manually add the 1.2.1 change to 1.3.0, although this doesn’t seem leverage TFS very well and leads to a rather unpleasant tracking experience.

A baseless merge is another potential option, though seems a bit ad-hoc and something I’d rather avoid if at all possible.

Comment: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=vsarbranchingguide

Comment: This is kind of a bad question since there could be large discrepancies between releases that result in undesired changes being merged. The severity of such a condition may be direction-dependent (I tested an "empty" merge of Main to a newer Dev branch and no changes were detected, but the other way will obviously have many). I'm still unsure if a cherry-picked baseless merge is a better route than manual propagation. I conjecture that the ladder may be preferred for very minor, isolated changes and the former for more involved ones.